# PDE with complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, several-complex-variables

I have a coupled PDE in complex variables which I want to solve. But I don't know how to start?

$$\frac{1}{1+\mid z1\mid^2+\mid z2\mid^2}-\frac{\partial y1}{\partial z1}-\frac{z2^*}{z1^*}\frac{\partial y2}{\partial z1}=0,~~\frac{1}{1+\mid z1\mid^2+\mid z2\mid^2}-\frac{\partial y2}{\partial z2}-\frac{z1^*}{z2^*}\frac{\partial y1}{\partial z2}=0$$
Where $*$ denotes complex conjugation and $\mid z\mid^2=zz^*$. So far I only know the solution to the case $z2=0,y2=0$. Which gives

$$\frac{dy1}{dz1}=\frac{1}{1+\mid z1\mid^2}$$
Whose solution is $y1=arctan(z1)+c$. But I have no clue on how to solve the coupled one. Please help?

Comment: Your special case does not make sense to me.  arctan is holomorphic so its z_1 derivative would be holomorphic yet your derivative seems to be real-valued, definitely not holomorphic.